# Ancestor-or-self issue at top level

Tags: xpath

With the following XML, the top level is returning the nodes of all levels. There are no ancestors for the top level, so why am I getting it’s children?

```
XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<WBSs>
<WBS GUID="2">
<Name>work</Name>
<WBSs>
<WBS GUID="1">
<Name>Wall</Name>
<ParentWBS>2</ParentWBS>
</WBS>
<WBS GUID="2">
<Name>South Wall</Name>
<ParentWBS>2</ParentWBS>
</WBS>
<WBS GUID="3">
<Name>North Wall</Name>
<ParentWBS>2</ParentWBS>
</WBS>
</WBSs>
</WBS> 
</WBSs>
```

XPATH
Note: Apply template is on .//WBS

```
<xsl:variable name="wbsCode" select=".//ancestor-or-self::WBS/@GUID[1]"/>
```

Note: I have an xslt instruction immediately following the xpath expression to strinify the nodes and include ‘.’.

Result

2.1.2.3

2.1

2.2

2.3

Desired result

2

2.1

2.2

2.3

XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="WBS_ELEMENT_TABLE">
   <xsl:apply-templates select=".//WBS" mode="I_WBS_ELEMENT">
     <xsl:with-param name="ProjectId" select="$ProjectId"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="WBS" mode="I_WBS_ELEMENT">
   <xsl:param name="ProjectId"/>

<xsl:variable name="wbsCode" select=".//ancestor-or-self::WBS/@GUID[1]"/>

<xsl:variable name="temp2" select="string-join(($wbsCode), '.')"/>

<WBS_ELEMENT>
    <xsl:value-of select="$temp2"/> 
</WBS_ELEMENT>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Instead of writing *Apply template is on...* and *I have an XSLT instruction immediately following...*, please just create include real code in an [mcve] that illustrates your problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Here's the relevant xslt code... sorry about that.

Comment: XSLT added above... sorry about that, it started out as an XPATH problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, so `//ancestor::*` means `./descendant-or-self::node()/ancestor::x` which finds all ancestors of all descendants, i.e. everything.

Get out of that habit of using `//` without thinking about what it means!